# extjs 4 autogenerating a record id

Tags: extjs4

I have a map to which features can be added and removed and am using an extjs 4 grid panel as a view (MVC) to list the features. The idea is that the user can click an item in the grid and highlight it in the map, click a button to remove it etc. The features do not have a natural key so I need to make one up, just a number is fine. At the moment the map starts up with some features already on it so I am able to loop through and give each an id and add a record to the store for each to tie the 2 up, but ideally I want the store to take care of that when each record is added. I also have the problem that when a new feature is created I need to get a fresh new id to use but I'd rather not have to loop through all my features to find the highest id.
I am using myStore.add({id:1,name:'blah'...}) to add the records - should I be using this or insert?
Any help appreciated

Comment: ok I have found that myStore.last() should get me the last record and am able to get the last id from there and add one. I'd still like to know whether the store can generate the ids for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the store last to figure out your last record, but my recommendation is to handle ID generation to the server side. Typically database sequencer is used to create IDs.